# Edit Data of Easytable Azure

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

Is there anyway to modify the data in Easytable Azure?

[image]

For example, I want to change the text for the first row to "testing 23/2". How to do that? Besides, I want to changed the deleted from true to false. Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, if you want to use easy table, you must connect to a database.
So if you want to change the data inside the easy table, you could find the table in the azure sql database and modify it.

You could find your database in the data connection tag.
[image]
Besides, I suggest you could install an MMSE and use it connect to your azure sql database, then you could modifty it by using MMSE.

More details ,you could refer to follow link and query:

Link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-connect-query-ssms

Steps:

1.connect to azure sql database
[image]

2.Select the table and edit it
[image]

Besides, I suggest you could also use send patch method by Restful API to update the row data.

---

Update:

Here is the execute image:
[image]

Result:

[image]

Besides, as I says you could use zumo-api to send request to the easy table to change the table’s result.

At first ,I suggest you could check the easy table’s permission.

You need set the update is allow anonymous access.

[image]

Then you could use [fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler/first-run) to send the request.

```
Method:PATCH

URL: http://YOURSSITENAMEHERE.azurewebsites.net/Tables/text/YOURROW’SID

Head:

Accept: application/json 

Content-Type: application/json 

Content-Length: 32

ZUMO-API-VERSION: 2.0.0 

Host: YOURSSITENAMEHERE.azurewebsites.net


Content:

{"text":"bbbl","complete":false}

Yours maybe {"TEXT":"bbbl","COMPLETE":false}
```

Like below image shows:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: I have tried your method and i can access my Easytable data. However, I cant commit after i made changes. Any solution?

Comment: According to your description, I have do the test on my computer again, it works well.Could you please tell me your MMSE version?I used the version is 2016.Besides, I have update my answer, you could also try to use zumo-api.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works. I guess it is my network problem when i tried last night.